# How to use Interface as a parameter type in SignalR hub method?

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr

I have a SignalR hub (`public class DatabaseHub : Hub`) and a class User that implements the interface IDatabaseObject (`public class User : IDatabaseObject`).

I want to add a method to `DatabaseHub` that takes any type that implements `IDatabaseObject` as a parameter.

I have tried:

*DatabaseHub.cs*

```
public Task DoSomething (User user) { ... }
```

*SomeFileOnClient.cs*

```
User user = new User(...);
databaseHubConnection.InvokeAsync("DoSomething", user)
```

Which runs perfectly fine.

However, when I change the hub method to:

*DatabaseHub.cs*

```
public Task DoSomething (IDatabaseObject user) { ... }
```

*SomeFileOnClient.cs*

```
User user = new User(...);
databaseHubConnection.InvokeAsync("DoSomething", user)
```

It does not run.

I have tried altering the servers Services but cannot find the right combination.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you get any sort of error you could share?

Comment: @Fildor No, the method is simply never called on the server. InvokeAsync does not throw errors when a matching method is not found

Comment: It _seems_ as if it has to be an exact match, then. I would investigate that and then maybe look for if that behavior can be configured.

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be something in `User` that is not expressed in the interface, and therefore it is not matching the schema for the hub method.

As per comments, using the as keyword to cast will not work. However, explicit casting should work (and does in my tests).

```
User user = new User(...);
databaseHubConnection.InvokeAsync("DoSomething", (IDatabaseObject)user);
```

Comment: Nope that still doesnt work. Visual studio says the cast is redundant and the method doesnt run.

Comment: Still runs if the param type is changed to User interestingly.

Comment: That's interesting. Does it work if you use an explicit cast to the interface? i.e.: databaseHubConnection.InvokeAsync("DoSomething", (IDatabaseObject)user)

Comment: Nope, the function isnt called and the IDE says that the cast is redundant. I added a workaround where there is a generic method in a database manager class and the parameters are just passed through to that from specific hub methods

Comment: This made no sense to me so I tested it myself. It actually does work if you use explicit casting. E.g.:             var testCollection = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
            await Connection.InvokeAsync("TestInterface", (IEnumerable<int>)testCollection);